# thymeleaf spring boot url mapping question get causing a repetition of word in url

Tags: spring, spring-boot, thymeleaf

i have a spring boot thymeleaf application where i am making a RequestMapping call

if you look at the image load-products.jpg i am getting the proper list but that happens only when i initiate the call the first time http://localhost:8080/services/searchByDepartment?department=iceMachines

i have links if you scroll down you will see the links

all refrigeration   ice machine  .......

[image]

if i click on any of the links a second time this url is called

http://localhost:8080/searchByDepartment?department=iceMachines

which creates error see attachment

[image]

so if i go back to my thymeleaf page and append services to all my th:href like this
th:href="@{services/searchByDepartment}

then i get a double services in my call which is creating another error

this is the other calls are creating
http://localhost:8080/services/services/searchByDepartment?department=refrigeration
http://localhost:8080/services/services/searchByDepartment?department=foodPreparation

you can see the words services are appearing twice which is creating a no explicit mapping error since it can not find the url mapping

i tried everything redirect, remove the word service from the controller adding it to thymeleaf and on and on its not working .. what is going on.. the code looks right to me like this

th:href="@{services/searchByDepartment(department='iceMachines')}

with the controller having   @RequestMapping(value = "/services") as an annotation or add it to the method call like this  @RequestMapping({"services/searchByDepartment"})

the directory structure seems fine to me but this code is not working

```
 <div class="prod-list">
        <a th:href="@{services/allList}" th:classappend="${activeAll}? 'active'"
           class="list-group-item">All</a>
        <a class="categories list-group-item ice" th:href="@{services/searchByDepartment(department='iceMachines')}"
           th:classappend="${activeIceMachines} ? 'active'">Ice Machine</a>
        <a class="categories list-group-item refrigeration" th:href="@{services/searchByDepartment(department='refrigeration')}"
           th:classappend="${activeRefrigeration} ? 'active'">Refrigeration</a>
        <a class="categories list-group-item cook" th:href="@{services/searchByDepartment(department='cookingEquipment')}"
           th:classappend="${activeCooking} ? 'active'">Cooking Equipment</a>
        <a class="categories list-group-item cook" th:href="@{services/searchByDepartment(department='foodPreparation')}"
           th:classappend="${activeCooking} ? 'active'">Food Preparation</a>
        <a class="categories list-group-item bar" th:href="@{services/searchByDepartment(department='barEquipment')}"
           th:classappend="${activeBar} ? 'active'">Bar Equipment</a>
    </div>



@Controller
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequestMapping(value = "/services")
public class ProductController {

    private final ServiceClientService serviceClientService;
    private final ProductService productService;

    @RequestMapping({"", "/", "/allList","/allList"})
    public String productList(Model model) {
        List<Product> productList = productService.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("productList", productList);
        return "services/allList";
    } 
     

    @RequestMapping({"/searchByDepartment"})
    public String searchByDepartment(@RequestParam("department") String department, Model model, Principal principal) {
        model.addAttribute("user", locateUser(principal));

        String classActiveDepartment = "active" + department;
        classActiveDepartment = classActiveDepartment.replaceAll("\\s+", "");
        classActiveDepartment = classActiveDepartment.replaceAll("&", "");

        System.out.println(classActiveDepartment + "+++++++++++xyz");
        model.addAttribute(classActiveDepartment, true);
        List<Product> productList = productService.findByDepartment(department);

        if (productList.isEmpty()) {
            model.addAttribute("emptyList", true);
            return "services/allList";
        }
        model.addAttribute("productList", productList);
        return "services/allList";
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Use context-relative URLs. Context-relative URLs start with `/`  like: `@{/services/searchByDepartment(department='iceMachines')}`

Comment: thank you my dear dear sir.. the feeling of euphoria when a problem is solved ...